# Approximation algorithm for TSP variant, fixed start and end anywhere but starting point + multiple visits at each vertex ALLOWED

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, traveling-salesman, approximation

NOTE: Due to the fact that the trip does not end at the same place it started and also the fact that every point can be visited more than once as long as I still visit all of them, this is not really a TSP variant, but I put it due to lack of a better definition of the problem.

So..

Suppose I am going on a hiking trip with n points of interest. These points are all connected by hiking trails. I have a map showing all trails with their distances, giving me a directed graph.

My problem is how to approximate a tour that starts at a point A and visits all n points of interest, while ending the tour anywhere but the point where I started and I want the tour to be as short as possible.

Due to the nature of hiking, I figured this would sadly not be a symmetric problem (or can I convert my asymmetric graph to a symmetric one?), since going from high to low altitude is obviously easier than the other way around.

Also I believe it has to be an algorithm that works for non-metric graphs, where the triangle inequality is not satisfied, since going from a to b to c might be faster than taking a really long and weird road that goes from a to c directly. I did consider if triangle inequality still holds, since there are no restrictions regarding how many times I visit each point, as long as I visit all of them, meaning I would always choose the shortest of two distinct paths from a to c and thus never takr the long and weird road.

I believe my problem is easier than TSP, so those algorithms do not fit this problem. I thought about using a minimum spanning tree, but I have a hard time convincing myself that they can be applied to a non-metric asymmetric directed graph.

What I really want are some pointers as to how I can come up with an approximation algorithm that will find a near optimal tour through all n points

Comment: You should post this question to http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Since you do not mind visiting same node multiple times, you can convert the weights such that triangle inequality holds. Eg. If a->c is farther that a->b->c in the optimal solution you are *never* going to use direct a->c. So it is better if you replace a->c with value of a->b->c so that your metric satisfies triangular inequality (where you can get better results).

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be getting a whole lot of love here. I'm voting to move it to cs.stackexchange.com - hopefully it will get some answers there. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify this problem to a normal TSP problem with n+1 vertexes. To do this, take node 'A' and all the points of interest and compute a shortest path between each pair of these points. You can use the all-pairs shortest path algorithm on the original graph. Or, if n is significantly smaller than the original graph size, use single-source shortest path algorithm for these n+1 vertexes. Also you can set length of all the paths, ending at 'A', to some constant, larger than any other path, which allows to end the trip anywhere (this may be needed only for TSP algorithms, finding a round-trip path).

As a result, you get a complete graph, which is metric, but still asymmetric. All you need now is to solve a normal TSP problem on this graph. If you want to convert this asymmetric graph to a symmetric one, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Asymmetric_TSP) explains how to do it.

Comment: This seems like the route to go with, keeping it simple while giving a plausible result. I went with this one and thus marked your post as the answer. Thank you very much for your time

Comment: This seems to try to find a (hamiltonian) path, so this answer looks correct to me, in the sense that solving one would solve the other. Your problem does not seem easier than TSP to me. It might be that you are also ok with repetitions (TSP-R), not that this has a different complexity

Answer (score 5):

To reduce your problem to asymmetric TSP, introduce a new node u and make arcs of length L from u to A and from all nodes but A to u, where L is very large (large enough that no optimal solution revisits u). Delete u from the tour to obtain a path from A to some other node via all others. Unfortunately this reduction preserves the objective only additively, which make the approximation guarantees worse by a constant factor.

The target of the reduction Evgeny pointed out is *non-metric* symmetric TSP, so that reduction is not useful to you, because the approximations known all require metric instances. Assuming that the collection of trails forms a planar graph (or is close to it), there is a constant-factor approximation due to [Gharan and Saberi](http://www.stanford.edu/~saberi/atsp2.pdf), which may unfortunately be rather difficult to implement, and may not give reasonable results in practice. [Frieze, Galbiati, and Maffioli](http://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Eaf1p/Texfiles/TSPapprox.pdf) give a simple log-factor approximation for general graphs.

If there are a reasonable number of trails, branch and bound might be able to give you an optimal solution. Both G&S and branch and bound require solving the Held-Karp linear program for ATSP, which may be useful in itself for evaluating other approaches. For many symmetric TSP instances that arise in practice, it gives a lower bound on the cost of an optimal solution within 10% of the true value.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a flaw in my answer. Fixed it now to make it metric.

Comment: First of all thank you for taking time to answer my question. I played around a bit with branch and bound but I failed to produce a result that worked to my liking. This is only due to my incompetence ( :) ) and not your answer. I did however manage to quite fine with the other post, so I took the liberty of marking that one as the answer, but thanks anyway!